# Work with multiple values from sql

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter

i have this sql command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PROCEDURA,DAY_SEND,EMAIL FROM FASTREPORT_SEND WHERE.....", con);
```

Output from this is for example this:

```
Procedura     Day_send        Email
procedure1       5        example@gmail.com
procedure2       3        example2@gmail.com
```

I want work always work with this three value. This is my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //Work with the values
}
```

How i could save this three values always into three different variables? Thanks for help..

Comment: Do you want to save all records in one variable? or use 3 different variables to store those values coming from 3 columns

Comment: You always want to work with the same 3 columns?

Comment: i want save 3 record into 3 variables..

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What are you supposed to do with those variables? What should be their types?

Comment: This three variables i want t ocall sql procedure later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class:

```
public class Procedura     
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Day_send { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create a `List<Procedura>` from the `DataTable` or directly from `SqlDataReader`.

```
var proceduras = new List<Procedura>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    proceduras.Add(new Procedura{ Name = row.Field<string>("Procedura"), Day_send = row.Field<string>("Day_send"), Email = row.Field<string>("Email") });
}
```

You can access the individual instances via indexer:

```
Procedura firstProcedura = proceduras[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Name i have (Form1) but i want (procedure1)

Comment: @Kate: I've [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19653157/revisions) my answer.

Comment: For example, how i could show this value in text box...if i have this :  textbox1.text= Name.ToString(); ....in text box i have this values...Form1 and after that Form2...but in text box should be procedure1 procedure2...

Comment: Sorry, that's confusing. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve and why it doesn't work. If you have two records you have two  `DataRow`s in the `DataTable`. Then the list contains also two instances of `Procedura`. You can access each of them via indexer(e.g. `proceduras[0]`) or you could get all and append for example the name of the procedura with comma via `string.Join`. For example: `string allNames = string.Join(",", proceduras.Select(p=>p.Name));`

Comment: The result od querry i have in the first post...but how i could show the name of procedure(procedure1) for example in textbox?